# How to automate picklist filter changes on reports when picklist values are renamed or replaced?

Tags: reporting, picklist, reports-api

We are replacing some picklist values. It appears Salesforce will update the API name of the old picklist value with the replacement picklist API name most everywhere except reports. We have more than 500 reports that reference the old picklist value in filters, and we have confirmed that when the picklist is replaced, the reports will stop working with this error:

[image]

So that users don't have to go through and update all their reports manually, is there any way we can replace the filter value for the users without opening each and every report? I thought of perhaps altering the report XML files one by one, but I am concerned this approach may come with unknown risks.

It would seem I am not alone in this challenge. There is an idea to add this feature in Salesforce:

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdjyqUAB/mass-update-filters-on-reports

Until this feature in implemented, is there a workaround to automate the replacement of filters when picklist values are renamed or replaced? For example, is there a way to access and modify the report filters using the API?

Other than reports, is there any other place we have to manually update picklist values when picklist values are renamed or replaced?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the possibility of platform events on metadata changes?  Or continuous integration tools that might be able to do search/replace actions?

Comment: @DavidCheng short answer no. However, are you implying that a possible solution is to search for the prior picklist API value in the raw XML and replace it with the updated one?